# "Cannot assign to named constant" (reassigning a variable)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm using a flag `f` for some error checking. Fortran (or maybe gfortran) won't let me reassign its value when I want to perform another check.

```
integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A
integer :: f, n        

write (*, *) "Give an integer n > 0. n = "

   read (*, IOSTAT=f) n

   do while(f /= 0)
      print *, "Error with input. Please try again."
      read (*, IOSTAT=f) n
   end do

   write (*, "(a, i5)") "You have entered n = ", n

   allocate(A(n), STAT=f)
   if (f /= 0) 
      print *, "Error: not enough memory for A."
   end if
```

NB: I think copy-pasting may mess up my spacing.

`f` has been declared as an integer (and not as a parameter integer): `integer :: f`.

I'm very much a beginner with Fortran, so it's very possible I've made some unthinkable mistake!

Comment: Is there an error when I say `allocate(A(n))`? Should it be `allocate(A(n,n))`?

Comment: this bizarre error message is a known bug in gfortran : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34325

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error message is confusing, but the problem is that

```
   if (f /= 0) 
      print *, "Error: not enough memory for A."
   end if
```

should be

```
   if (f /= 0) then
      print *, "Error: not enough memory for A."
   end if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   implicit none
   integer :: f, n
   integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A


   write (*, *) "Give an integer n > 0. n = "
   read (*, *, IOSTAT=f) n

   do while (f /= 0)
      print *, "Error with input. Please try again."
      read (*, IOSTAT=f) n
   end do

   write (*, "(a, i5)") "You have entered n = ", n

   allocate(A(n,n), STAT=f)
   if (f /= 0) then
      print *, "Error: not enough memory for A."
      !exit program. How do I do this?
   end if
```

This seems to work.

(1) As Vladimir F pointed out, Fortran wanted `if (<condition>) then <stuff> endif`.

(2) As I mentioned in the above comment, I should've written `allocate(A(n,n), STAT=f)`.

Thanks for all your help! This answer is just here for completeness - Vladimir was the one who actually answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

@Vladimir F.

Thanks. I had the same problem but by just simply changing the arrangement of words to exactly how you wrote them the problem got fixed. I was writing:

```
If ( n == 1 ) then call expTot
```

Instead of:

```
If ( n == 1 ) then
Call expTot
```

I can't believe such a simple arrangement of words can really cause a big damage.